# Ionic 3: increasing the number of items when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to increase the item on the item page when I click the button on the button page.

****different pages****

button page:

[image]

item page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your .html file :

```
<button (click)="increase()">increase</button>
<ion-item>{{myNumber}}</ion-item>
```

in your .ts file , define this before constructor

```
myNumber: number = 0;
```

then after constructor write this function :

```
increase(){
    this.myNumber+=1;
}
```

Comment: It did not work. Can you tell in more detail?  item and button two separate pages meanwhile

Comment: You want to increase the item on same page right? Just change the increase() function in my code , replace this.MyNumber=+1 to this.Mynumber=this.Mynumber+1;

Comment: no will increase on different page, the photos I took belong to different pages

Answer (score 0):

> in your .ts

```
export class yourPageClass{

  count: number = 0; //Here you'll initialize it just once and we'll access it in the function



  countup()
  {
    this.count++;  //instead of reinitializing, we are using already initialized variable
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.count));
  }
```

> in html file

```
<button (click)="countup()">increase</button>
<ion-item>{{number}}</ion-item>
```

passing values

```
this.navCtrl.push(page2,{
item:count
});
```

accessing that count

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html',
})
export class Page2 {
value:any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.value = navParams.get('item');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad EmiCalPage');

  }

}
```

Comment: it works, however, I want the item on another page to increase each time a button is clicked